# wifi adapter tplink tl-wn8200nd V3 help :(

Tags: wireless, adapter, tp-link

I'm new in Linux's world so I'm sorry if this is really basic stuff. Im trying to use my wifi adapter but this model V3 doesnt have official drivers. Now I'm using my phone as hotspot bc ethernet cable is not possible at the momment. What can I do? Should I get a new one?

Comment: What results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hLi9ukm6

Comment: Basics starting point as I see it is what OS/product/release you're using, which you've not told us.  Ubuntu LTS releases offer two kernel stack choices; and switching to the other kernel stack changes kernel modules (commonly called *drivers*) but knowledge of what you're using is required to know what options exist for you.